# Accumulating variable out side a loop (padre perl)

Tags: perl

```
$num = 1; 
print "          Number\n";
print "Number   Squared\n";
while ( $num <= 50 )
{
   $numSquared = $num * $num;
   printf ("%3d %6d\n",$num,$numSquared);
   $num = $num + 1;
}

print "End of Program\n";
exit 0;
```

I am trying to create a variable that will accumulate the total of the number and numbers squared within the loop. This is using padre perl. All i have so far is the numbers and numbers squared displayed

Answer (score 1):

All you need are two variables for your totals:

```
# Your two variables to track the sums:
$total_sum        = 0;
$total_square_sum = 0;

$num = 1; 
print "          Number\n";
print "Number   Squared\n";
while ( $num <= 50 )
{
   $numSquared = $num * $num;
   printf ("%3d %6d\n",$num,$numSquared);
   $num = $num + 1;

   # Summing with those variables
   $total_sum        += $num;
   $total_square_sum += $numSquared;

}
print "Sum of numbers: $total_sum    Sum of Squares = $total_square_sum\n";
```

I take it you're learning Perl. In that case, you should get a good book on Modern Perl.

- Using `use strict;` and `use warnings;` can catch many errors. This is why he uses `my` to declare variables.
- A `for` loop implementation in this case is cleaner and is much easier to understand. For example, looking at your `while` loop, it's hard to tell where it starts or how `$num` gets changed. The `for` declaration makes it easy to see all of these things. The loop goes from 1 to 50, and the `for` loop handles the incrementing.
- It's standard to use "C" Style curly brackets rather than Java style curly brackets (that is, the first bracket on the same line as the first line of a `while`, `for`, or `if` statements).

Here's a *more* modern way of writing your program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables
use feature qw(say);

my $total_sum        = 0;
my $total_square_sum = 0;

print "          Number\n";
print "Number   Squared\n";
for my $num ( 1..50 ) {
    my $numSquared = $num * $num;
    printf ("%3d %6d\n",$num,$numSquared);

    $total_sum        += $num;
    $total_square_sum += $numSquared;

}
print "Sum of numbers: $total_sum    Sum of Squares = $total_square_sum\n";
```

Comment: I've deleted mine in favour of yours. You might want to delete the references :)